# Override devise registrations controller create action

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my application I am using devise invitable gem for sending invitations. By this if I am sending the invitation then the entry goes in users table.
If the invitation is sent and then I am not able to sign up in the application with same email. For that I have to override devise registration create action that if invitation_token is present then allow the user to sign up. How can I do that.
I had written the following for overriding:

```
def create
  email = params[:user][:email]
  user = User.find_by_email(email)
  if user.present? && user.invitation_token.present?
    user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    sign_up_steps_path
  else
    super
  end
end
```

But I am getting the error: `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template users/registrations/create`

Comment: `sign_up_steps_path`, looks like u are trying to redirect here, did u tried this `redirect_to sign_up_steps_path`

Comment: Yes actually I have wizard. After I sign up two more screens are there. I had also tried redirect_to sign_up_steps_path. By this I was getting redirected to sign in screen but not to my wizard.

Comment: hmmm.then If I am not wrong u need to `sign_in user` then redirect to the next steps OR else u need to assign the user to @user and try rendering the next page from sign_up steps

Comment: What I have to do is that even if the user is sent invitation and before accepting if he tries to sign up in the application then allow him to signup.

Comment: tat is fine. after updating the user attributes u need to do a `sign_in user` Or else device will catch the user as non logged in user and will redirect him to sign_in page, Also it looks like, sign_up_steps_path is checking the whether the user is logged in or not, `before_filter :authenticate_user!`is the code that is redirecting to sign_in page

Comment: That is what I want the solution for that the devise is not taking it to sign_in page but should complete the wizard

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43927/discussion-between-sneha88-and-abibullah-rahamathulah)

Answer (score -2):

Say tour controller name is RegistrationsController and the code look like this

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
```

change it to

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```